# Remove duplicate records with timestamps

Tags: mysql

I have a table in my DB where I keep track of user data. So I have rows like that:

```
(row_id,user_id, stat1,stat2,..., statN, timestamp)
```

Now I want to remove all duplicate records, where user_id and stat columns are the same, but only between other rows with different data. So if I have

```
(row_id, user_id, stat1, stat2, stat3, timestamp)
(1,1,1,0,1,1000)
(2,1,1,1,1,2000)
(3,1,1,1,1,3000)
(4,1,1,0,1,4000)
```

It should became

```
(1,1,1,0,1,1000)
(2,1,1,1,1,2000)
(4,1,1,0,1,4000)
```

And not

```
(1,1,1,0,1,1000)
(2,1,1,1,1,2000)
```

So I want to save record progression but remove meaningless duplicates.

Comment: Marco, thank you for markup, first time asking question here and from mobile :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
delete t1.*
from `table` t1
inner join `table` t2
  on  t1.user_id = t2.user_id 
  and t1.stat1=t2.stat1
  and t1.stat2=t2.stat2
      /* ........... */  
  and t1.statN=t2.statN
  and t1.timestamp>t2.timestamp
left join `table` t3
   on t1.user_id = t3.user_id 
  and t3.timestamp > t2.timestamp 
  and t3.timestamp < t1.timestamp
where t3.user_id is null;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d611358e31738a9384f3fb79db60cd0c)

Comment: Yay! Looks like exactly what I need! Will test it in few hours. Than you very much.

Comment: @BlackSwan There can be a problem if the combination `(user_id,timestamp)`  is NOT unique.

Comment: It should not be, but I will check for it, thanks

Comment: @BlackSwan I do not know your task, but I think the uniqie index by the expression above may be usable... not only the check/deletion you need now. On the other hand it can affect on some soft causing errors, so be carefully.

Comment: Hm... Just put it in to phpMyAdmin on duplicate table of data set, it sez 
Error #1093, Table that changing t1 cannot be used in FROM

Comment: Well, I'll edit... done.

Comment: Thank you for working solution. Meanwhile I got similar result by splitting it to two request. First one detects and lists row_id's of all unwanted rows (kinda just removing first row of your solution and adding "SELECT row_id" before second one). Second request deletes all rows which row_id was listed by previous request.

Answer (score 0):

So doing a join on the elements that constitute a duplicate and the last where criteria shows which to delete.

```
delete t1
from table t1, table t2
where t1.user_id = t2.user_id and t1.stat1=t2.stat1
     and t1.stat2=t2.stat2  and t1.stat3=t2.stat3
and t1.row_id+1=t2.row_id
```

Comment: Isn't it going to transform data in that way?(Which is unwanted behaviour)

    (row_id, user_id, stat1, stat2, stat3, timestamp)

    (1,1,1,0,1,1000)
    (2,1,1,1,1,2000)
    (3,1,1,1,1,3000)
    (4,1,1,0,1,4000)

                \/

    (1,1,1,0,1,1000)
    (2,1,1,1,1,2000)

Comment: why would it? Delete can only remove rows, it can't transform. Try on a test dataset to confirm this outcome.

Comment: I can't test it right now, but I believe you are missing the point of question. Look again at the question, please. I afraid that request will return result as in unwanted case with only two rows survive deletion. I need preserve duplicates that are separated from each other by rows that are different

Comment: So `and t1.row_id+1=t2.row_id` as the final part of the query would solve this?

Comment: @danblack No guarantee of holes in row_id. Moreover, I cannot see guarantee of (t1.timestamp>t2.timestamp) => (t1.row_id>t2.row_id).

Comment: O, we almost here. But still not exactly... There are many users in DB so same rows can have not coinciding row numbers, but they should go one after another in select * from table order by user_id. Will it help somehow?

Comment: I would add an sub-query that gives the `min(row_id) ... group by the 4 fields` and remove all rows that do not have one of these `row_id`s. Do not know the MySql syntax for this.